# matching department in login

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a small part of intranet for my college using php with css and mysql. i have created a database called "mop" which is my college name. it consists of 2 tables - students(regno,name,dept,year) and staff(id,password,dept). i have made this form for staff login. after the login is made it checks for the id and password in the staff table and here is the php that thr above form refers to:

```
$myid = stripslashes($myid);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myid = mysql_real_escape_string($myid);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$myid' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
$_SESSION['myid'];
$_SESSION['mypassword']; 
 header("location:form3.php");
 }
```

if the login is successful it goes to a menu with view/insert/delete student database option and based on the option it goes to the page accordingly. here is the view coding (for eg) of options:

```
   <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","staff","123456","mop");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student");
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Register No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['regno'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['department'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['class'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

now my problem is if a staff of particular dept say CSE or ECE logs in then the staff should be able to view only the students who are of the same dept(this should be done automatically and dept selection shouldnt be done through drop down lists or radio buttons or any other method). i have an idea but unable to implement it. the value of dept from staff table should be stored in some variable say $dept and in my view/insert/delete page i should be able to manipulate the query accordingly like $sql="select * from student where department=$dept";

i am unable to implement this. can anyone of u tell me how to do it?
is this possible? or any other work around for this??

Comment: do you have dept id in staff table? post code that you use for menus? like insert update delete

Comment: You are really using [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) and [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) in the same application?

Comment: yes it works fine. why?

Comment: Because it results in poor quality code.  Also, you appear to be storing passwords as plain text.  That's another hallmark of poor quality code.

Comment: thanks for the info. i am not actually worked about the security issues. i just want the project layout to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a `session_start();` at the beginning of your PHP code and then
after

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

put

```
$_SESSION['myDept'] = $result['dept']
```

This is the dept from staff table, it will be stored in the $_SESSION array. 
This array have a session time live.

Then in each code ( this one or another PHP ), since you have putted a `session_start();` you will have access to the $_SESSION array. So you will have acces to your "dept".

So you are able to make a SQL to select only the student in the staff dept.

Comment: after using what u said above i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$count' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\checklogin.php on line 37            also how do i implement this mydept in mysql query?

Comment: It will be hard to see without your code. Please post at least the part of the buggy code.

Comment: sir i have added details about the code and more detailed description pls re read the question. i have edited it.

Comment: @YeshwanthVShenoy Don't dump all your code here, nobody has the time or the inclination to read it. You would be much better off just posting the relevant bits of your code.

Comment: am sorry guys but am new to stackoverflow and to php kindly co operate

Comment: modded to the question to minimal code. please check guys. i need help  urgently.